# Getting "Killed: 9" response for certain commands in terminal Mac (Ventura)

Tags: macos, terminal, mac, bash, ventura

I have been playing around installing a few software using homebrew and I don't know what happened, but now I am getting Killed:9 error message when trying to execute say the `ls`, `cp` commands, etc. I am not able to run webpack also for my web app.

However, commands like `mkdir`, `open`, etc run successfully.

I tried re-installing bash, tried using PowerShell also. But none of them is working.

Can you help me recover the corrupted things if any and to overcome this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after multiple searches and tries, I ended up in a single solution that was easy to understand.

Reinstall Ventura using the recovery mode. Ideally no backup needed.
Feels just like upgrading the OS.

- Restart your Mac:
- Press Ctrl+R
- Choose reinstall Ventura.
- Restart Mac again.